# WooCommerce Memberships: How to adjust query to account for delayed content/content drip?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I'm trying to build a query that shows the latest post a member has access to, but I cannot find what parameters to add so that posts that they have access to in the future are removed from this list.

Does anyone know how to do this?

### If not, can `wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted( )` be adapted into a custom loop?

**EDIT**
I tried adding the code suggested, but instead of getting the latest post a user has access to, it outputs the oldest page on the site. Am I adding it to the wrong place?

```
`<?php
    // Query Test
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'premium',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'notebook',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 425,
            ),
        ),
      );
    $query4 = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query4->have_posts() ) {
    // The Loop
    while ( $query4->have_posts() ) {
    $query4->the_post();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if( !wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted($post->ID)){

      echo the_title();
    }
    }
    } wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove restricted post titles select "Hide Completely" on Settings -> "Content Restriction Mode."

If you select "Hide Content" post titles will continue to show up on post navigation and lists.

Once I did this both loops (mine and mujuonly's) worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if( wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted($post->ID)){
        // do the coding here for the restricted contents
    }else{
        // do the coding here for the non-restricted contents
    }
}
```

Try this code

Comment: Thanks! This helped me see that I made some errors with my code.